# String or Unicode type required, wxPython StaticText

Tags: python, text, wxpython, label

I'm trying to make a wxPython static text widget. For some reason I keep getting the error below.

Snippet:

```
self.Label = wx.StaticText(self, pos=(sw/2.0 - w/2.0, sh/2.0 - h/2.0), label='hello')
```

Error:

```
", line 238, in make_label
    self.Label = wx.StaticText(self, pos=(sw/2.0 - w/2.0, sh/2.0 - h/2.0), label='hello')
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-ansi\wx\_core.py", line 8500, in SetLabel
    return _core_.Window_SetLabel(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: String or Unicode type required
```

Comment: I think you need to set the `parent` also, if I am not mistaken?

Comment: I can not reproduce the error. Only difference is that my version of wxPython is the unicode version

Comment: Can't you just change the call to `..., label=u'hello'`?

Comment: I figured out what the problem was; however, I'm unsure why it's a problem. I only seem to get this error while naming my widget self.Label. If I name it anything else it works. self is a wx.Frame, so I'm not all to sure whats happening. However, at least no I can move forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Label is a property of wx.Frame, and trying to assign anything other than a String to it is not allowed.
For reference: http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html#SetLabel (wx.Frame is a subclass of wx.Window)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify all the argument names , self is being taken as datatype of some sort not as an argument, So in your code your have to replace `self` with `parent = self`