# String or Unicode type required for dfgui running wx with kivy python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, kivy

**I intended**
to write a code which helps me display Table / Dataframe on GUI (Kivy). To which I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28935315/how-do-i-display-a-pandas-dataframe-as-a-table-in-a-simple-kivy-app). Apparently it uses a non-official package from a github [repo](https://github.com/bluenote10/PandasDataFrameGUI) which is dfgui.

**The Problem**
occurred to me when I executed as told on StackOverflow link. However returned Error that

> wx._core.PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "!items.IsEmpty()" failed at
>   /usr/include/wx-3.0/wx/ctrlsub.h(154) in InsertItems(): need something
>   to insert

**I Brokedown**
the problem by selective execution in foll. way

```
import dfgui
import pandas as pd
xls = pd.read_excel('Res.xls')
df = pd.DataFrame(xls)
dfgui.show(df)
#dfgui.show(xls) Apparently the same as df
```

which then returned

> TypeError: String or Unicode type required

and led me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125377/string-or-unicode-type-required-wxpython-statictext#5156733)  link, which I couldn't understand much.
Point me in North, or perhaps a different solution could be great too.

Comment: Sorry, do you found the solution?
I have exactly the same problem and for the moment absolutely no idea where is the problem.

Comment: @PaulZakharov Sorry mate, I scored Tumbleweed for this question!